# Load local files(CSS or JS) into website of choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load my own coded CSS into a website that I do not own or have server access too. This is for perdonal use only. My problem is I dont know if there is a plugin available to do this; in chrome or firefox. Is there any easy way to do this? How do I do it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add css through developer tools, not as file, copy and paste to existing

Comment: For Firefox, http://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/how-to-override-css-stylesheets-in-firefox/

Comment: Well I dont want to copy paste it every time I go in to the website. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this: 1. First, plugin as you ask for, there is one called [User Stylesheet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-stylesheet/nlfpnjpcddafclelkbgijfpdanaacdcp) for Chrome and [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) for Firefox
2. You can edit C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css directly for Chrome
3. You can use dev tool in both Chrome and Firefox to temporary change the element styles.

Just saw you asked for custom javascript as well, you can use Greasemonkey for Firefox and Tampermonkey for Chrome.

Comment: Also, if you have a Greasemonkey-formatted userscript, one can install it by dragging it into `chrome://extensions`, just as one could install extensions.

Answer (score 1):

**Stylebot** is a chrome extension that does the very thing. Use [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) or if it doesn't work, just go to `chrome://extensions` then get more extensions and search for **Stylebot**

**But** still it won't let you add your own CSS file. It would just allow you to change the CSS of the website and it will store them for you so that whenever you'll visit that site, it would show you the same styles.

Comment: Can I load Javascript aswell? And will this be applied every time I go in to the website, this should be great!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way for the javascript

Comment: What JavaScript functionality do you want to load into each site you visit?

Comment: @user2979821 And yes the css will be applied everytime you'll visit the site.

Comment: I would like to load Javascript to move around elements on the website :)